# share common data in wars under ear

Tags: maven, jboss, ear, data-sharing

To reduce database hits, I've used static variables to store data from database.
At time of `WAR` deployment this data is stored in these variabes as it is not changing so frequently.
This scenario was working fine as the scope was with only single a `WAR`. Now I have another application where I need access to these varibles
But due to different application scope,I'm unable to access them in another application.

Also I'm having an `EAR` which encloses both above `WAR` and one `JAR` containing some common buisness logic of both `WAR`s.
So under `EAR` is it possible to share these variables via `JAR` or using some different approach?

If any `javaEE` concept can help in this scenario, then please let me know about it also.

I'm using `maven` with `Jboss7.1.1.Final` for this

Answer (score 1):

You should use Infinispan, the built-in caching mechanism of JBoss 7 https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Getting+Started+Guide+-+JBoss+AS+7. Caching data in static fields is generally frowned upon in Java EE.

However should you still want to cache your data in static fields you need to make sure the class with the cache was to be shared across all WARs. This means you have to create [skinny WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html)s.

Comment: ok.Thanks Philippe Marschall and Surge I'll check for Infinispan.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need an Enterprise Caching Solutions. There are lots of choices on the market. They include but not limit to

Open Source framework

1. Memcached
2. EHCache
3. Infinispan (mentioned by Phillipe)

Commercial product

1. Oracle Coherence
2. GigaSpaces XAP
3. GemFire

For your second question, as long as your JAR is deployed in the `EAR/lib` folder, you should be fine.